# Infer shape of result of Object.fromEntries() in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a better definition for `Object.fromEntries()` that infers the actual keys and values of the resulting object.  I have what I thought would work, but apparently `infer U` is scoped in a way that my method can't find `U`.

```ts
interface ObjectConstructor {
  fromEntries<
    K extends PropertyKey,
    V,
    A extends ReadonlyArray<readonly [K, V]> = ReadonlyArray<readonly [K, V]>
  >(array: A): {
    [key in A[number][0]]: A[number extends infer U ? U : never][0] extends key ? A[U][1] : never;
  };
}
```

The `U` in `A[U][1]` is inaccessible.

> Cannot find name 'U'.

Another issue is that `A[number extends infer U ? U : never][0] extends key` seems to always evaluate to `false`.

How can I retrieve the index of the array associated with `key`?  I'm guessing there's some hacky type that wraps the array in a function and checks to see if that function extends something that can infer the index, but my best attempt didn't work.

```ts
type ArrayIdxOf<A extends readonly unknown[], K> =
  (((i: keyof A) => A[typeof i]) extends ((i: number & infer U) => A[typeof i] extends K ? typeof i : never) ? (i: U) => U : never) extends 
    ((i: number) => infer U)
      ? U
      : never;

const a1 = ['foo', 'bar'] as const;
type A = ArrayIdxOf<typeof a1, 'foo'>; // type A = unknown

interface ObjectConstructor {
  fromEntries<
    K extends PropertyKey,
    V,
    A extends ReadonlyArray<readonly [K, V]> | Array<[K, V]>
  >(array: A): {
    [key in A[number][0]]: ArrayIdxOf<A, key> extends infer I ? I extends number ? A[I][1] : never : never;
  };
}

const a2 = [['foo', 'foo'], ['bar', false], [1, 2]] as const;
const x = Object.fromEntries(a2);
/**
 * const x: {
 *   foo: never;
 *   bar: never;
 *   1: never;
 * }
 */
```

If *at all* possible, I also want to eliminate the `readonly` constraints of `A`.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=2&ssc=30&pln=2&pc=23#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAhiAkgEwB4HkBmAeGKCDYCAOzQGco4JE0B7MgGxCgFcyBrMhgdzIBtALoAaKAGkAfFAC8AWABQUKAAp1ASwBcULhBAMcsAJRyZMQaEiGoG4aeKkK1TTrLsAtgCMIcKADJbMhxfKABVU1lzS3AIGzsiEnIqSSgAfigrOKMNKDcIADdfUwzVbXDImTC8qDJC4sSnFKUVFVdazx84SqCQvwiW1pUMsMGh-KK4AG4lJQBjJkpgKEQ5KEEAchwGBg3xDa9EOA3hFeoFsiWZxSzYNfgkVExcPCybRH3t3akpqAB6P6ZWJ3WQcbi8ASzRRoCBzZhHaAAc2YDEOzCgAG9BhoyKQ4DhEHNoFgvAArWHAADCi2AcHYc2ADD8WOUrRwcAYHgAori4BoIJQ8GNWhJGslqAAFDmQOCgCT6UTClQANUVrKGhEc4qgACU6IwWCAHsg8LR6ExWOsJOJlcIZAAfWAIE2Ca1QW1SYVSVRHR46GDGHQsoZDQR6Ng42CCdzeXzCQQABmEwn9zqe2HwMHE4ZkWucvVCKHSUCLeZSMa6xYsKHjAEZThNQo3pkqoABfa4qNtKbuKeY0qBeNaCTZfPZQLY7E7iTaHY7iAnMSgQMTrWviABMybOUAuV37l2WGDWJPJDIAdOzOTzafzKKovMZrn8AFQvlov3cDjBBj9snbNp2n4qHOgF-iotZgcon69lAL5-FCxBgEyywYu2UxAA) though while this compiles using `tsc`, it doesn't compile in the playground, so I don't know how useful it will be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd probably do something like

```
declare global {
  interface ObjectConstructor {
    fromEntries<
      A extends ReadonlyArray<readonly [PropertyKey, any]>
    >(array: A): { [K in A[number][0]]: Extract<A[number], readonly [K, any]>[1] }
  }
}
```

Note that `readonly` isn't a constraint, but a loosening... `string[]` is assignable to `readonly string[]` but not vice versa.  By accepting `readonly` arrays you are accepting *more* things, not less.  So I'd leave them on (which is good because [`as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) tends to produce `readonly` things).

This will work with your example:

```
const x = Object.fromEntries(b);
/* const x: {
    foo: "foo";
    bar: false;
    1: 2;
} */
```

---

If you want to give the compiler a hint that it should try to read the first element of each tuple as a [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) type, you can give it this modified definition:

```
declare global {
  interface ObjectConstructor {
    fromEntries<
      P extends PropertyKey,
      A extends ReadonlyArray<readonly [P, any]>
    >(array: A): { [K in A[number][0]]: Extract<A[number], readonly [K, any]>[1] }
  }
}
```

This will work the same on your `as const` version, but will also work if you pass the array literal directly:

```
const c = Object.fromEntries([['foo', 'foo'], ['bar', false], [1, 2]]);
/* const c: {
    foo: string;
    bar: boolean;
    1: number;
} */
```

---

You can tweak the inferences a bit, but the basic approach is to use the [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu) utility type to pull the appropriate tuple out of the array.

Anyway, hope that gives you some direction.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBzCB7ARlC8DeBYAUPPAJYB2ALiDAGZRgIDyaAVuOQMIqkDO5MArmHIoYOAkSLUYKALYBRCjGIhuAHnESiABXggAHpVLBu8LdIAOVcgE8A0iGsAaDZoCCugyCMmASiCjAXBDWrjAwUNaqcAFB1vAA2lqO8FCk1gC6AHwu8JkAFLDh1gBc8K4AlKXYCbYkpGXxpPwyaFTp8QAM6emlcgbhQqqujc2tMOnJ0YGkwTXJqRmZ8QCM6fAAvhqb+NsEYFy88GjwALwJ8QDk1CgoF8lXNxcTCRcYMHfwtBDcIM8ryQAmbopEz7HjkADcewO5HgelO8CYrCEADopLIFHxlNw8mhylD8AB6ABU8DBhz0VRy1xQpQARDS6QTNG9Sl8fsyJMtSgCCet4MTCfACCL8OTYWAEUi2GjpPJFNi8vFLjSPg9bn9XrAPuzfsl-vAgel8QQSWSYWSqYQJDTSrwlKREJyiKyjjcIP5SM74Nz4E0WlQ+QLCaL9OYRLDqusIUA)

Comment: I had never heard of `Extract` before.  Bravo.  And of course it's @jcalz, because who else would it be?  ;D  You've answered *sooo* many of my TS typing questions.