# Cannot apply Array prototype extension to readonly arrays in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript

This is a continuation of [Infer shape of result of Object.fromEntries() in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63061180/infer-shape-of-result-of-object-fromentries-in-typescript), though you probably don't need to read it to know what's going on.

I am trying to extend the `Array` prototype to add a shortcut around `Object.fromEntries()` if the array is the right shape for it.

```ts
// the aforementioned question uses this signature for Object.fromEntries() replacing `this` 
// with a parameter `array`
interface Array<T> {
  objectFromEntries<
    P extends PropertyKey,
    A extends ReadonlyArray<readonly [P, any]>
  >(this: A): { [K in A[number][0]]: Extract<A[number], readonly [K, any]>[1] };
}
```

This works fine if the array is not `readonly` but its elements are, but does not work on readonly tuples of arrays.

```ts
const works = [['a', 1] as const, ['b', 2] as const];
let obj = works.objectFromEntries();

const doesntWork = [['a', 1], ['b', 2]] as const;
obj = doesntWork.objectFromEntries();
/**
 * Error message:
 *   Property 'objectFromEntries' does not exist on type 'readonly [readonly ["a", 1], readonly ["b", 2]]'. ts(2339)
 */
```

I've tried unioning `A` with a bunch of variations, but none of them work.

```ts
    objectFromEntries<
      P extends PropertyKey,
      A extends
        ReadonlyArray<readonly [P, any]> |
        Array<readonly [P, any]> |
        ReadonlyArray<[P, any]> |
        Array<[P, any]> |
        readonly [...readonly [P, any][]]
    >(this: A): { [K in A[number][0]]: Extract<A[number], readonly [K, any]>[1] };
```

Ideas?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbwL4G4CwAoTATYBjAGwEMpg4BzAiAIyIMUzjgEsA7GYKAMyLzIHlqAK3wwAwhFYBnGFACueGNAYYmTLlAgBbAKLsozYFIA8jNUwAKcUB1bYpcC5rCcYATwDSwNwBoz5gEFrEFt7OAAlYCJsSQI3AKgoIjdjUmjYtzgAbQsfOCJWNwBdAD5-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)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple and obvious.  I needed to add the method to`ReadonlyArray<T>` as well.