# Double expand nested variadic tuples in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, variadic-functions

**tl;dr**: I want to strongly type the following.

```ts
const foo = [ 'a' ] as const;
const bar = [ 1 ] as const;
const baz = [ true ] as const;

const concatted = foo.concat(bar, baz);

type Concatted = typeof concatted; // expect ['a', 1, true]
```

I've figured out how to add definitions for 0..n arguments, but I want to do it for an arbitrary number, preferably with one or two definitions.

---

Suppose I have:

```ts
const strArray = [ 'a' ] as const;
const numArray = [ 1 ] as const;

const concatenated = strArray.concat(numArray);
```

We *know* that concatenated is exactly equal to `['a', 1]`.  I've figured out how to write a type definition for `concat()` that gives us this.

```ts
declare global {
    interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
        concat<
            A extends ReadonlyArray<T>, 
            I extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>
        >(this: A, items: C): [...A, ...I];
    }
}

type Concatenated = typeof concatenated; // => ['a', 1]
```

However, JavaScript's `Array.concat()` takes in an arbitrary number of arrays.  So now, let's do

```ts
const strArray = [ 'a' ] as const;
const numArray = [ 1 ] as const;
const boolArray = [ true ] as const;

const concatenated = strArray.concat(numArray, boolArray); // => [ 'a', 1, true ]
```

Prior to TypeScript 4's [variadic tuples](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0-beta/#variadic-tuple-types), the solution was something like

```ts
declare global {
    interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
        concat<
            A extends ReadonlyArray<T>, 
            I extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>
        >(this: A, items: I): [...A, ...I];
        concat<
            A extends ReadonlyArray<T>,
            I1 extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>, 
            I2 extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>
        >(this: A, item1: I1, item2: I2): [...A, ...I1, ...I2];
        // ...additional concat() definitions through I_n...
    }
}
```

I was hoping that with TypeScript 4, I could do something simpler

```ts
declare global {
    interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
        concat<
            A extends ReadonlyArray<T>, 
            I extends ReadonlyArray<ReadonlyArray<unknown>>
        >(this: A, ...items: I): [...A, ...(...I)];
    }
}
```

This apparently doesn't work.  I'm guessing there's some black magic using the

```ts
((val: ReadonlyArray<ReadonlyArray<unknown>>) => void) extends ((val: [infer U, ...infer R]) => void)
    ? [...U, ...<something something recurse with R>] 
    : never
```

pattern that I've never gotten the hang of, perhaps in tandem with magic using `Extract<>` as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63061643/3120446).

It would be very nice if types could be recursive without any magic.  Then I could easily write:

```ts
type Concat<T extends ReadonlyArray<ReadonlyArray<unknown>>> = 
    T extends [ReadonlyArray<unknown>, ...infer U]
        ? [...T[0], ...Concat<U>]
        : [];

interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
    concat<
        A extends ReadonlyArray<T>, 
        I extends ReadonlyArray<ReadonlyArray<unknown>>
    >(this: A, ...items: I): [...A, ...Concat<I>];
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOBBe8CGBPGBeGBtA5KvgLoyoQyiRQDcAsAFBXQxgCuAtsmpjrgIylylcNHpNRsAEYgQAG24ZseKPDYBTIRWa1GjHSLDBUUAHKdlCRegB0VY1AAU7LigwBKcQfsnzXMAAmAEKycpaq1nbgDs6c1gA0MDLy1p56DAD0AFRZjDBZMOoAHgAO6sBQAFx4hPiJgnkFqBVsqHLVBET1xI1wbMDA6hAQ1aoajRmMUOhlMADC0b4WONNlIABmhg5+4ozZuQz5haXlVTVdMPyJY5q9zVCt7TCOtTAAPpfvMDfuuD2HBQg-UGw2q6zaEHUEymM3U80WZjigRC8mUq3UGy2S38wVCNBg6QC5TkqHgcIA5nIQFI2jAAN55GAASzAUHU8HBgxg1gAPAAVAB89MZMBgGQyMHWIHgrHAAFoHiU5EMRVioDyAJICxw2XVMtkcEbwowmXlav7uaq8vlfLXiUUAX3SopZbI5zThACV1KgAuA5OhrUKGYdRWqearRYhjmzAhRvb7-YG3Oh+QL4pH5jH1HGYAm-WAA7y2GAANZgEAAdzAAtV2qgAAsmUbEIl9epDdU5pa8LqbK2YH25sRdqHReKYHyAPIAESnqonPnVC4lUezufzSaDGbHYtXWeKsYC8Z9BaLKZ5m8LyZ4PJL5arNdru4n9abLcSffbnfmPdwfYHPsdV1bsR2dMNFwRCMX33aNDxzY881PLcL0FHcwz3MM5nXRCr3PW88JvDA7zLCtqwFZ8MNfRxG2bK1Pz1A0jW7DoAIYmwFhNdU5gFMCGBXSU2jkGlgFLb4QFlMAFTYJUoV3JdNRwk9E2vXlCOLUjHwo7UvyY6oNR7a0vmsPlYR5EyzK1Cj7RgJ0GDsmFZgsso02UG14I3ZDVIvFl1nZGAAFUhQAfkCmBqjAdQADd2VHCd0WNBx+SUpCVPw4j1Ive8yKfIUcD2fdRXcoojwoXBMtvbKtPY3z-IC-4JwwjDQv-XU+VwAAGYh2M4pKgoawqmo6PjGGKEppVgOlbJoIA)

As an aside, I've never understood why recursive types--as long as they resolve within n depths--aren't supported.  Infinite recursion, of course, would be bad/impossible, but I would think this syntax could be supported for tuples of size 100 or less pretty easily/efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official support for [recursive conditional types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40002) will be added in Typescript 4.1
With it in place we'll be able to:

```
type Concat<T> = 
    T extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail] 
      ? Head extends ReadonlyArray<unknown> 
        ? [...Concat<Head>, ...Concat<Tail>] : [Head, ...Concat<Tail>]
      : T
```

The above definition allows to pass arrays and/or values to concatenate into a new array (just like regular [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat))

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200911#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOBBe8CGBPGBeGBtA5KvgLoyoQyiRQDcAsAFBXQxgCuAtsmpjrgIylylcNHpNRsAEYgQAG24ZseKPDYBTIRWa1GjKOgAO6mAGFwwVFAA8AFQB82RjBi2Y6gB5R1YACYVcAEswADN1eBgACXVUXwAaGAA6ZOCwiNtUQLliZxcYAH4omN93Lx9-GAAlYvA5dEV0azYwAGswEAB3MHtcvIK8ZMTzMEsbaNj7BMHh0btMuXtSAC48cfik5JmrOazF3pgV2z0GX3VgOVR4EwBzORApVDkYAG9c4O94ENRgE2rY2vqKAwdkcrwYfSos32LkQpW8fgof18AIaILi0JgAEk4eVETUwHVUc02p1uvt7AAKKAAC0CEBWiCmKW8HHpWIAlCtcINGRshhZtpjFuIXABfRjihiMHQiEZWHzyko4BANRKQqwU9hcIHoBIyeQNBL4EKyfBkbSSBJfOQQEzCHQJFU69niAD0rrwACJUJ6EvwEqoNAlPSaQL6YNbbcGfTkpQxPIYQPBYM8YKKaEA)

---

The recursion limit is 50 nested type instantiations

Comment: Could you explain why this doesn't completely flatten the whole array? Given this definition, I would expect `([0] as const).concat([ 1, [ 2, [ 3 ] ] ] as const)` to return `[0, 1, 2, 3]`, but it correctly returns `[0, 1, [ 2, [ 3 ] ] ]`.

Comment: More specifically, how would you alter this *so* that it recursively flattens the array?

Comment: `T extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]` -> `T extends readonly [infer Head, ...infer Tail]`. Still trying to understand if that's bug or feature 