# Strongly type a map of object keys/values to an object with the same keys but different values in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I commonly need to take an object and produce a new object with the same keys but with values that are some mapping from KVP to some `T`.  The JavaScript for this is straightforward:

```js
Object.map = (obj, fn) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(fn));

// example:
const x = { foo: true, bar: false };
const y = Object.map(x, ([key, value]) => [key, `${key} is ${value}.`]);

console.log(y);
```

I am trying to strongly type `y` in the example above.  Building off [Infer shape of result of Object.fromEntries() in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63061180/infer-shape-of-result-of-object-fromentries-in-typescript), I tried:

```ts
type obj = Record<PropertyKey, any>;

type ObjectEntries<O extends obj> = {
  [key in keyof O]: [key, O[key]];
}[keyof O];

declare interface ObjectConstructor {
  /**
   * More intelligent declaration for `Object.fromEntries` that determines the shape of the result, if it can.
   * @param entries Array of entries.
   */
  fromEntries<
    P extends PropertyKey,
    A extends ReadonlyArray<readonly [P, any]>
  >(entries: A): { [K in A[number][0]]: Extract<A[number], readonly [K, any]>[1] };

  map<
    O extends obj,
    T,
    E extends readonly [keyof O, T],
    F extends (entry: ObjectEntries<O>, idx: number) => E
  >(obj: Readonly<O>, fn: F): { [K in E[][number][0]]: Extract<E[][number], readonly [K, any]>[1] };
}

Object.map = (obj, fn) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(fn));

const x = { foo: true, bar: false } as const;
const y = Object.map(x, entry => [entry[0], `${entry[0]} is ${entry[1]}.`]);

type XEntries = ObjectEntries<typeof x>;
type Y = typeof y;
/**
 * XEntries = ['foo', true] | ['bar', false]
 * Y = { foo: never; bar: never; }
 */
```

Mousing over `.map` shows that `T` isn't being inferred; it is of type `unknown`.

[image]

What's baffling to me is that even if I manually specify `T` is `string`, `y` is still `{ foo: never; bar: never; }`.

```ts
const z = 
  Object.map<
    typeof x, 
    string, 
    readonly [keyof typeof x, string], 
    (entry: ObjectEntries<typeof x>, idx: number) => [keyof typeof x, string]
  >(x, entry => [entry[0], `${entry[0]} is ${entry[1]}.`]);

type Z = typeof z;
/**
 * Z = { foo: never; bar: never; }
 */
```

Any ideas?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA9gRgKygXigJQgYxgJwCYA8ACjjJDqANIQgA0UAhgHYgB8A3ALABQPokUAPKIswAKJNgOAJYQAzgUFQIAD2AQmeObESsUUAN48oUANoBrGlGlMolkDABmQgLoAuM-fqCLNFy65uAF9fB2dBAJ4ePCwAGwYcaBt1HEcGTGhhBFEAYRgmOSkAV0xgXENjKAB6ACoayqgaqABZXCTJCFjY6QBzDWAoGMx4nAZgaXyoR3KAAyzRADpHUgBbCSlZORmoYAALMcGIFJWbeR3d6Dl9gSdz6ES5ItjgemlnaQHMZgWGpoABMAJBgrZSSGRnACCOFGIFgzn64LkP24JkaVUqyxgazBmwIDSgRGUag0WgJpHIVBotHxEKJ6k02gwDDw+ViIChMIIiWZrNhpiI9GYIBcrEqrAAFAjNh4IQBKDwGMyUay2CGmJhFFZwCA4FymAAM-g8YjUo1KBDVGq1Opc9G5LKYbKVgpYItMAEYXFAgoFKisGGA8SjUUpVPTSfAENTgyYACrR1FQMR0knae28zw0W6Ceix234gBiKYZUElYJAHnmpXWiMUrFeeBUHit2pwspQejEYvFkY8TIdbLr9EcTA8BflhiVKqTpj1LZtBqNSdN6WABDEs-Vmtbtqg6cdfMoLuFrA9Xp9PCCUW4VeAC39YH0PcQw6Y7eQelvS1WNc24q-UryM+CCyveAbiiOsqyr63DYAUAwqPoirTDAHjFBA9BwAkHhpLEcjQEEjDaHBhSBCRAywqgX4PuKKj0AilF6KYDGLvQMwACQGCxhqEdI2icSxnpBAsMwuNB178NAAAav5nFRIjVji8gEJJtwqBwfDgNAACa+iqc4ICBLU9Qok0MlKdoqCmAA5Ch1n0OhXoAD5mNZWE4PZUwMHhEAuMYTS6agyEwKhUBMBAABuOrsFA7nNpF0Xev56K8LB+SFFAABe+iVNRAZBom+lQHRUD4oUMhMD09D4vuTqhLcRUleVNg9Lu+JllIFZCAp4gWSpWlqfW1iNs2246u+TH2A1A3OE1GyVX5wYSiVDEdmY3G7hxXHlouvH8dtnVnsJonialklQAAWnpM1ZUZdT+ZdSFTCF8VRTgMVxWFCXvUlplVEAA)

Comment: There's a lot going on in the question; the function implementation doesn't necessarily preserve the keys, does it? If the callback returns key-value pairs it could presumably change keys. Do you want to support that or not? As for typings, I see a lot of type parameters which might not be inferrable because there's no direct inference sites for them. I could maybe rewrite these so they work, once I understand the deal with keys. Also I doubt you'll be able to get anything much more useful than a `Record<K, V>` type out of this without a lot of weird annotation of the callback.

Comment: Reiterating this after looking at the code more:  Do you need to support mapping keys to other keys? if not, the function's callback should only return values, not key-value pairs.  If so, then we might need to make all the output properties optional since `map({a: 0, b: 1}, ([k, v]) => [Math.random()<0.5?"c":"d", 2])` should be `{c?: number, d?: number}` and not `{c: number, d: number}`.

Comment: And: will you ever do the transformation where the output object has different types for different properties?  I can sort of imagine expecting `map(obj, e => e)` to produce an output of the same exact type as `obj`.  But any callback more complicated than the identity function will likely result in something the compiler only sees as a record-like type. For example, `map({ a: 0, b: "one" }, ([k, v]) => [k, k === "a" ? true : new Date()])` is going to produce `{a: boolean | Date, b: boolean | Date}` and nothing more specific without implausible assertions. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/ymAPBN)

Comment: The function implementation does preserve the keys.  Don't need to support mapping keys to other keys.  And yes.  For instance, if I just did `map({ a: 0, b: 1 }, entry => entry)`, I would expect a shallow clone of the object to be returned.

Comment: The implementation only preserves the keys if you call it with a callback that preserves the keys.  If you don’t need to allow keys to change, then why are you supporting it in the implementation?  If the callback is `()=>["k",0]` then the keys will not be preserved.

Comment: Oh, right, I meant that the function's type needs to preserve the keys. ‍♀️

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm just going to answer as fully as I can and hope that your use case is in there somewhere.  First I'll try to assess the specific problems you were running into:

- The thing that caused failure even when manually specifying your types was using `Extract<T, U>` to try to pull out the entry corresponding to a particular key.  The `Extract<T, U>` splits up a union `T` into members, and checks that each one is assignable *to* `U`.  If `T` is `["foo" | "bar", string]`, and if `U` is `["foo", any]`, then `Extract<T, U>` will be `never` because `"foo" | "bar"` is not assignable to `"foo"`.  It's the other way around.  So maybe you want an `ExtractSupertype<T, U>` which keeps only those elements of the `T` union *to which `U` is assignable*. You can write that like this:

  ```
  type ExtractSupertype<T, U> = T extends any ? [U] extends [T] ? T : never : never;
  ```

  If you use this in place of `Extract` and remove `readonly` (since `any[]` is a subtype of `readonly any[]`), you can get something to work. e.g.:

  ```
  ExtractSupertype<E[][number], [K, any]>[1]
  ```
- Inferring four type parameters from a function that takes only two arguments is not likely to go well  You don't really need to infer `F` as anything that `extends` its constraint.  The constraint is good enough:

  ```
  map<
    O extends obj,
    T,
    E extends readonly [keyof O, T],
  >(obj: Readonly<O>, fn: (entry: ObjectEntries<O>, idx: number) => E): {
    [K in E[][number][0]]: ExtractSupertype<E[][number], [K, any]>[1] };
  ```

Those changes should make your previously broken stuff work, but there's plenty of other stuff in there I'd recommend changing (or at least would want to hear some explanation for):

- I don't see `T` as a useful type parameter to try to infer.
- I don't see the point in `E[][number]` or that `obj` is typed as `Readonly<O>` instead of just `O`.
- I don't understand why you are constraining `E[0]` to `keyof O`.  I would think either allow the keys to be changed, in which case just constrain it to `PropertyKey`, or *don't* allow the keys to be changed, in which case don't accept a callback that returns keys at all.

---

I'm going to give some alternative implementations for this `map()` function (I'm not going to add it to the `Object` constructor since since monkey patching built-in objects is generally discouraged) and maybe one of them will work for you.

The simplest possible thing I can think of is to have the callback only return the property values and not the keys.  We don't want to support changing the keys, right?  So this will make changing the keys *impossible*:

```
type ObjectEntries<T> = { [K in keyof T]: readonly [K, T[K]] }[keyof T];

function mapValues<T extends object, V>(
  obj: T,
  f: (value: ObjectEntries<T>) => V
): { [K in keyof T]: V } {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    (Object.entries(obj) as [keyof T, any][]).map(e => [e[0], f(e)])
  ) as Record<keyof T, V>;
}
```

You can see that this behaves as desired in your example case:

```
const example = mapValues({ foo: true, bar: false }, entry => `${entry[0]} is ${entry[1]}.`);
/* const example: {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
} */
console.log(example);
/* {
  "foo": "foo is true.",
  "bar": "bar is false."
} */
```

There are limitations here; the most notable one is that the output object will have all properties of the same type.  The compiler won't and can't understand that a particular callback function produces different output types for different input properties.  In the case of an identity-ish function callback, you can expect the implementation to do the right thing but the compiler to widen the returned object type to a record-like thing:

```
const widened = mapValues({a: 1, b: "two", c: true}, e => e[1]);
/* const widened: {
    a: string | number | boolean;
    b: string | number | boolean;
    c: string | number | boolean;
} */
```

Personally I don't see this as much of a problem; obviously you're not going to be passing the identity function to `map()` (what's the point?) and any other function that does something novel (e.g., turns `number` values to `string`) is not going to have its effects magically inferred by the compiler:

```
const nope = mapValues(obj, e => (typeof e[1] === "number" ? e[1] + "" : e[1]))
/* const nope: {
    a: string | boolean;
    b: string | boolean;
    c: string | boolean;
} */
```

Even if you go through the trouble of declaring the callback as a generic function that does the right thing, the compiler cannot perform the higher order reasoning in the type system to get the return type of `f` as something that changes depending on its argument type.  There are some GitHub issues which have asked for that (I think [microsoft/TypeScript#40179](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40179) is the most recent open issue about this) but nothing is there so far.  So even with more effort you get widened types:

```
const notBetter = mapValues(obj, <T extends ObjectEntries<typeof obj>>(e: T) =>
  (typeof e[1] === "number" ? e[1] + "" : e[1]) as
  T[1] extends number ? string : Exclude<T[1], number>)
/* const notBetter: {
    a: string | boolean;
    b: string | boolean;
    c: string | boolean;
} */
```

Oh well.

---

If you *do* want to support transforming the keys as well as the values, I'd suggest allowing the keys to become any `PropertyKey`, and you will probably need to make the output `Partial` because the compiler cannot guarantee that every possible output key actually is output.  Here's my attempt:

```
type GetValue<T extends readonly [PropertyKey, any], K extends T[0]> =
  T extends any ? K extends T[0] ? T[1] : never : never;

function mapEntries<T extends object, R extends readonly [PropertyKey, any]>(
  obj: T,
  f: (value: ObjectEntries<T>, idx: number, array: ObjectEntries<T>[]) => R
): { [K in R[0]]?: GetValue<R, K> } {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(f as any)) as any;
}
```

This is as close as I can get to your original code.  It does about the same thing as yours to the original example, except for the optional keys:

```
const example2 = mapEntries({ foo: true, bar: false }, entry => [entry[0], `${entry[0]} is ${entry[1]}.`]);
/* const example2: {
    foo?: string | undefined;
    bar?: string | undefined;
} */
console.log(example2);
/* {
  "foo": "foo is true.",
  "bar": "bar is false."
} */
```

You need those optional keys though; supporting keys being changed means you can't tell if every possible output key will actually be produced:

```
const needsToBePartial = mapEntries(obj, e => e[0].charCodeAt(0) % 3 !== 0 ? e : ["oops", 123] as const);
/* const needsToBePartial: {
    a?: number | undefined;
    b?: string | undefined;
    c?: boolean | undefined;
    oops?: 123 | undefined;
} */
console.log(needsToBePartial);
/* {
  "a": 1,
  "b": "two",
  "oops": 123
} */
```

See how `needsToBePartial` at runtime is missing the `c` property.

And now for more limitations. An identity function does the same widening thing as before, to a record-like type:

```
const widened2 = mapEntries(obj, e => e);
/* const widened: {
    a?: string | number | boolean;
    b?: string | number | boolean;
    c?: string | number | boolean;
} */
```

You *can* promote the callback to a generic and actually get a tighter type, but that's only because the union-of-entries input type becomes the same union-of-entries output type:

```
const widened3 = mapEntries(obj, <T,>(e: T) => e);
/* const widened3: {
    a?: number | undefined;
    b?: string | undefined;
    c?: boolean | undefined;
} */
```

Anything you do which is more novel than an identity function suffers the same problem as before: it is hard or impossible to tell the compiler enough about what the callback function does to have it infer which possible output goes with which possible key, and you get a record-like thing again:

```
const moreInterestingButNope = mapEntries(
  obj, (e) => [({ a: "AYY", b: "BEE", c: "CEE" } as const)[e[0]], e[0]])
/* const moreInterestingButNope: {
    AYY?: "a" | "b" | "c" | undefined;
    BEE?: "a" | "b" | "c" | undefined;
    CEE?: "a" | "b" | "c" | undefined;
} */
```

So even though this version uses an `Extract`-like return type to try to match each input entry with a corresponding output entry, it really isn't very useful in practice.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=4.1.0-dev.20201027#code/C4TwDgpgBA9gRgKygXigJQgYxgJwCYA8ACjjJDqANIQgA0UAhgHYgB8A3ALABQokUAUQAewHA0zAAygFdyfCAQAq9AKqsUURVAgiITPAGdGLKAH4oAbRUBdbbv1GLi2+a0AuKEwgA3CDigeXr44XNw8eFgANgw40ACWTMB+AGbi0ADyiFjAAMIwTAai0hK4UADePFBQALYMYASVVVDpdkkOsIi0jVXK3YKteoZQsQx4+ZEglgDWNDDJzfTOXdxNUKwAFPAIHhij4yAE6az0yUwe63qiIB6ZCNkCiThxEAaHx1BxeEKB0tVwfgBKFDqAQAjwVFarSyUD5MQQWawWJi-f44REABms1g8wlE4iksj88gIAgRSJRfms9AslHozBA1lYFgAjLYAL6hNk8Hi3bIAOlqYA0m06UFOQOQ6l5Ej5yVI1QeomeBnW0uAfMuTxeIoQAIFdXW4qBDCM9NCPGwBWAUCEGjKYpgMA8RQg9DgMQ8qUiBmgbMYRkthVCgetk1Qav1YHWQnomrD6gscYsmPoAAMACRlJOYv1xIyZpOstl81PWAHm3jgaAADUVWqM4ayEjryoI8jmNo4PHkUAAmhp2-MQBWLflClAAF4oRoRwUNSFVQc25arQpPJgAcxXTRGYyYE2ms3mS5jUDXCQ31kaG1PceBlmzVKgGazjxAyesufzr6uLM-JbLCsewALQHKsOwnEduAAelguD4IQxDuUrfg1RbF4lHUVB7RpWEoBmEAO2cDxd32aFFhpLEoDZCwCKI6wK2SaQmAkOJ8hqOoADUGEiaQMK0HQ2iGLZsnoTiNkaLYPF6SFknObweL4m4m2AdDXkUVgJXUTieDBcpoTwuj5mIqBOOo8pGliYBpBwOEIzlGAFUeZV1j6VUVI1ZztS2Y1HCMzQ6RYREy0jC570TD8TguAEy0aXz0CwXBCH85RTK7bguTCbgQzsBhqjASJoFQQVuN47V7WSR1nRwPi3Q9MUeJ9ajYzfe8X0fL8oALN8-2LVNyx4aCACooBygw4nywrCnBPpKqdM8lU3UJVndHAPHPJaeD9IboNHAoYEKvlIhgDcLiEPKCogAaYJGiEqgAIjm+6PEex0PiMF0+Xu7d7tW56oF+mJ3oa70IC+raoB25Ccq2O1GA8Zk3Re4AAHcYG+0bqr46iKxylHPj0CA8A0ErFO80UivUCA-2u4bRrHa18YiLw8Bmhd4YW9cNygAAfTwKX8Pm4EdQrmGWpo4HWxbub55E-j8XmoGFg6IDFvpMClrnFbl1FFeV0WmE5SHdqynKmDIIqOLAUq+JVLZY3vdYl2p1kUGQVB7p1vx7rMbQ-ygABqAGfY8F2ywBQaRrNi22dWBhNYvPWRdVw2+klznE6F5O1fZjWM83JOVZz7aTb28dzeAAAhCBgCSfxiq4sm7dFJQBnaNCvNeJctlYDYIGkrTGid8D5jDt2Pa9nAffMMeg-ukO-dZXzGkUf3BMGIxJ99jbuZxIRMF4iIlD-ehJ80yP6atTwYCrmu69jpp4-zmWlez1P2fTnfC4N8Wqjzr+s5F3fiXZCg14KgJQtAAA4jXG2CgBL2CGKRfckwLAkAthQEA1A6DGAZPQGE692ir0xFhFebchj0l9gQxBRhiEuE0P7QIPgFZMOCIxZirF2KCjUq3QhwkVL0DQOQowyCDxoNIHILBNBAoMgkpCKSAVGhySgOsBSZVlJ3GbJ3TC9BPjfH5vLHAdIcBiGuM0FSPCNIIi0ugXS4IDIJHQB+awpgPAwOAHAggaB8HqD9HdYYNcbJ2Q8g5JySptQRk1C5HyoV5gmlwQCeKZotrQwZrlSaEAABMJM6hqXWBVKqUAXR1TWiDJqbIWpXHCo+NM3Vfw5mBnUnA74iwAVplHNJOgLqFUyQ-Koc1XHP0VsxCIyQEhE1-krGIgyAFQBGRAMZLMjZQ2ymOFWR0TpnW6Vk9pFlISvXRi9OawNPrfUaIDKeL1VrAy9D6cGGVjapKvl4ImBhFAwGrkQGIwA4g8RyWAPJ9ttD3mppiPkmAAAWMQ8gRAAILAHWOiIEABSKAABmKAABCd2UB0S+2gB4Cw91HRgAMBjZkmS0W2HiSGXZZsICvPeZ875vzIh9MYIMrefN5mLImWnGZ0thn6AWeMvAkzMCDP1inIVozRWTJJQYQZFKMXcuFbysVEMVmBnWcdU6LzDBMogF8igrLdn+Pugwf6iNzlwH+vdVG6MfoKqtZSzVpdVlXyZoTPA2SG4As7jqB2kptB0rSV6lm7KGACq1rLAW38U6TLgNGzOBjdaAJ-urZNBdY2GPjcXR5psw0ExZhiv1gKW7KD7gPEFobPXFqJmiyNnK42qtlUs-lCds1zLVXKzNHgpXMBlSK9tDyVll2tNUXAEAACSiQ-AvB+ZuSu0hgAADkLb-LyZJUU0Vwr5I5vdWFvZewY3TvdSuAgBAYzzvdHIl6fZ+hpQzAEEVMRPlBViCON1L7jknbEWddcF0XmXWumOezVhHt7IMi1Ps+a-VgwDTACGeW9vZhegQ0HLWK3g9hpDQ71WTLvRhl6WG4O2tw8hntI6QFZR4EAA)

Comment: Wow, you went all out on this one.  I'm impressed.  I came to the same conclusion about limiting the mapping function to just the property value a couple hours ago.

Comment: One-and-a-half years later... what purpose does `T extends any ? ... : never` serve?

Comment: It [distributes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) the operation over unions in `T`.  `type G<T> = T extends any ? F<T> : never` will evaluate `G<A|B|C>` as `F<A> | F<B> | F<C>`.  If you just write `type G<T> = F<T>` then `G<A|B|C>` is just `F<A|B|C>`.

Comment: Ahh, thank you!